# React Native: Save Multiple contacts to phone contacts

Tags: reactjs, react-native, contacts, react-native-contacts

I have lists of contacts in array. Now I want to save that contacts in my phone contacts using **react-native-contacts** library. So Is it possible to achieve this functionality using react-native-contacts package or any other package.

Using react-native-contacts we can save one contacts at a time using openContactForm(). But what if save more than one contact at a time.

Please help me out with this issue. I have checked all package but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

openContactForm() is not the method you're looking for as it requires the user to enter contact details by hand. react-native-contacts provides an addContact(contact) API where you can store a contact directly to the phones address book. So for an array of contacts you can use something like this:

```
for (contact in contactArray) {
  addContact(contact);
}
```